# Questions About Pleasure in Visual Senses

Tags: mindfulness, perception

I'm wondering if Buddhism has any notion of visual defilement. What I mean is that in Christianity, there are notions of one's purity or person corrupted by pornography, lustful gazing, etc.

Is there an equivalent in Buddhism? Also, if a person perceives pornography or gazes lustfully, is this sufficient to be a kind of attachment if there is no action or consequence?

I.e. What is the consequence of visual pleasure without further action? What is the consequence of perceiving a pleasurable sight *without* intention, e.g. mindfully?

Thank you.

PS: What is the scope of such pleasure compared to say orgasm or eating? Is there a pleasure specific to vision, e.g. one becomes accustomed and insensitive to visual pleasure specifically with overuse? (But not, say, other sensory pleasures)

Answer (score 3):

In Buddhism, there are three types of kamma (action), namely: (i) bodily; (ii) verbal; and (iii) mental; each of which have results. Therefore, habitually merely visually observing pleasurable objects will making craving, addiction & the resultant restlessness grow. Thus, the Jesus teaching is similar to Buddhism; because viewing a woman with sexual objectification both grows craving, enslavement & is an error of moral-view (lacking of compassion & not considering harmful consequences).

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism is the path to get Nirwana (End the cycle of life). According to my knowledge Buddhism is not restricting any activity but teaching how it will affect to the path of Nirwana. If someone obligate with something which make affection to life, Buddhism describe it as not to do. For an example lust will make affection to this life cycle. So if someone has lust for someone or something, he/she will not able to understand the impermanence of life.